# How to link a sub form to a from in Access using two primary keys

Tags: vba, ms-access, menu, subform

In access I am trying to make a navigational subform. However, my current code only works with one primary key. Does anyone know haw to change code so that it works when the primary key is made up of two fields??

My current code is as follows;

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me.Parent.RecordsetClone

rs.FindFirst "[Fist Primary key]= " & Me![first primary key].Value & ""

If rs.NoMatch = False Then
    Me.Parent.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End If

Set rs = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an `AND` statement

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me.Parent.RecordsetClone

rs.FindFirst "[Fist Primary key]= " & Me![first primary key].Value & " AND [Second Primary key]= " & Me![second primary key].Value

If rs.NoMatch = False Then
    Me.Parent.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End If

Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: I keep getting a missing operator error on the FindFirst line

Comment: Try the edited version. Now it assumes both primary keys are numbers, I made an error earlier since I assumed you were using text fields (because of the `& ""` which actually just does nothing)

Comment: It works now! :). Sorry, I should have made the datatype more clear.